# How to get the stream key of a particular page of facebook using graph api in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming

I have referred this link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started but could not get answer.

I need "134902671......?s_bl=1&s_sc=134902691.....&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbyURQDWoQ-jNWNr" this stream key of page.

func getPageDetail(dict: [String:Any]) {

```
    var request: GraphRequest?
    let accessToken = AccessToken.current?.tokenString
    print("{accessToken-\(accessToken)-}")
    
    let params = ["access_token" : dict["access_token"] as! String,
                  "page_id" : dict["id"] as! String
                 ]
    
    request = GraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me/live_videos?access_token=\(accessToken!)", parameters: params, httpMethod: HTTPMethod(rawValue: "POST"))
    
    request?.start(completionHandler: { (_, result, _) in
        
        print("result-........\(result)-")
        let dict = result as! NSDictionary
        let id = dict.value(forKey: "id") as! String
        
        let streamUrlStr = dict.value(forKey: "stream_url") as! String
        let lastCom = streamUrlStr.components(separatedBy: "/")
        let finalStr = lastCom.last!
        print(finalStr)
      })
```

}

The finalStr which I am getting here does not match the stream key which is there in the page.

Comment: What's the output of `print("result-........\(result)-")`? Because the doc you gave is the starting point, but not the api of `live_videos`.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/

Comment: Could you give the output of result? Also, `(_, result, _)` would you mind checking the `error` parameter and not forget it? That's the first step in debugging when it's not working: ``(_, result, _)` => ``(_, result, error)` ... `print("Error: \(error)")`

Comment: Output is 
{
    id = 3047102405406333;
    "secure_stream_secondary_urls" =     (
    );
    "secure_stream_url" = "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/3047102405406333?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sc=3047102532072987&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbxgLHJcS7o_Kwqr";
    "stream_secondary_urls" =     (
    );
    "stream_url" = "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/3047102405406333?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sc=3047102532072987&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbxgLHJcS7o_Kwqr";
}

Comment: So you want `3047102405406333?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sc=3047102532072987&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbxgLHJcS7o_Kwqr` or it's not the same as the one you expect?

Comment: Yes, I want stream key which is same as 3047102405406333?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sc=3047102532072987&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbxgLHJcS7o_Kwqr but this key does not match the stream key of page of facebook which is "135016687999085?s_bl=1&s_sc=135016701332417&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abz9sEVGtrRpzCtJ"